# ¿Cómo saber qué palabras clave están presentes en un texto, incluso por indirecta con python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

¿Cómo saber qué palabras clave están presentes en el texto, incluso haciendo pistas con python?

```
# Texto a analizar 
text = "El posicionamiento de nuestra empresa de 15 años es ofrecer productos de calidad a un precio asequible." 

# Lista de palabras clave a buscar 
palabras_claves = ["posicionamiento", "conocimiento", "país de origen", "edad"]
```

Intenté:

```
import re

for palabra in palabras_claves:
    if re.search(palabra, texto, re.IGNORECASE):
        print(f "La palabra clave '{palabra}' está presente en el texto.")
    else:
        print(f "La palabra clave '{palabra}' no está presente en el texto.")
```

Pero solo devuelve `posicionamiento`. Por lo tanto `edad` podria ser detectado hasta que se trata de `nuestra empresa de 15 anos` ...

Comment: Los regex buscan coincidencias exactas, lo que necesitas es una librería que analice la intención o significado del texto para detectar las coincidencias, puesto que para ti conociendo el significado de "edad" y "años" es muy fácil ver la relación, pero si no conoces el significado, no se parecen absolutamente en nada. Es decir, esto no puede hacerse con regex

Comment: Que una computadora sea capáz de interpretar el lenguaje natural, es algo muy dificil que no se puede lograr usando unicamente regex. Requieres un programa que sea capáz de interpretar cada palabra y combinación de palabras. Y aun así, necesitas reconocer el contexto. Por ejemplo "ella es una zorra". Esa frase dependerá del contexto el hecho de que "zorra" se refiera al animal o al insulto. Por supuesto, hay librerías muy buenas para ello. Incluso podés usar la propia api de Chat-GPT